# Lost data during update iOS version on TestFlight of FlutterApp...help me?

Tags: flutter, xcode, testflight

To reproduce this error, first you need to install a build version (for example, version 14). Then, you need to generate some internal audio files within the application. After that, if you update the system to, for example, version 15, you will notice that some of the audio files are not persisted.

I made a video on youtube to explain my point: https://youtu.be/fbZ5okq2ddo

I am a Flutter developer. The problem is that after the build update, some data persists while others do not. The program generates several audio files during its normal use. Some of these audio files are generated directly by recording with a microphone, while others are generated by concatenating pre-existing audio files. Interestingly, the audio files generated by concatenation are not persisting after the build update.

Here is the address of one of the audio files in the set that is not persisting: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7288BFF-6A62-49BF-961C-615C17DAE0FE/Library/Application Support/guerreirodafogueiragmailcom_autocura_folder/transMentaltmenv4yT2uHbj8G9p6T.mp3

And here is the address of one of the audio files that is persisting: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7288BFF-6A62-49BF-961C-615C17DAE0FE/Library/Application Support/guerreirodafogueiragmailcom_autocura_folder/revoltas.mp3

Other data, such as lists of strings and images, are not lost. Any suggestion to solve this issue?

The iphone used to run the app: IPhone SE iOS 15.7.5 My XCode version is: 14.2 (14C18) My Flutter doctor result: [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm, locale pt-BR) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2) [✓] VS Code (version 1.77.0) [✓] Connected device (3 available) [✓] HTTP Host Availability